# How to apply different audio filters in multiple audio tracks using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Folks.

I'm trying to apply different audio filters in multiple audio tracks using ffmpeg but with no luck so far. Here's my command (Windows):

`ffmpeg.exe -y -i "movie_in.mkv" -map_metadata -1 -map 0:v:0 -c:v copy -map 0:a:5 -c:a ac3 -b:a 384k -map 0:a:1 -c:a ac3 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -af:a:0 acompressor=attack=15:release=300:threshold=-25dB:ratio=15:knee=1dB:makeup=10dB -af:a:1 "volume=-10dB" "movie_out.mkv"`

The output file is with both audios with 192k and with only the last filter applied (volume=-10dB).

So, with my command, ffmpeg are ignoring the bitrate and channels set for audio 0 and also ignoring the filter compressor for audio 0.

Log:
https://pastebin.com/4BgcSfhi

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-filter_complex`:

`ffmpeg.exe -y -i "movie_in.mkv" -map_metadata -1 -filter_complex "[0:a:5]acompressor=attack=15:release=300:threshold=-25dB:ratio=15:knee=1dB:makeup=10dB[a0];[0:a:1]volume=-10dB[a1]" -map 0:v:0 -c:v copy -map "[a0]" -c:a ac3 -b:a:0 384k -map "[a1]" -ac:a:1 2 -b:a:1 192k "movie_out.mkv"`

Comment: Worked very well. Thank you very much.